# Discord.py: How do I get a role from a tag a user inputs?

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a Discord Bot which has 2 main functions - creating a channel for a user only they can access, and letting them invite people into their channel. Right now, the first part works, but the invite part doesn't.

Firstly, here is the code that lets a user give themselves a role, which works fine and adds the role:

```
if message.content.startswith('!!start'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello {0.author.mention}! Welcome to The Hangout. We are about to setup your account here! Hang on..'.format(message))

    print(message.author)

    overwrites = {
        message.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        message.guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        message.author: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True)
    }

    await message.channel.send('What would you like your apartment to be called?')

    msg = await client.wait_for('message')

    print(msg.content)

    apartments = discord.utils.get(message.guild.categories, name='Apartments')
    print(apartments)

    channel = await message.guild.create_text_channel(str(msg.content), overwrites=overwrites, category=apartments)

    await message.channel.send('Done! Next, we will setup a role which people can use to invite you to their apartment by.')

    await message.channel.send('What would you like your role to be called? (please be sensible, people will use this to invite you.)')

    msg = await client.wait_for('message')

    await message.guild.create_role(name=str(msg.content))
    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=str(msg.content))
    await message.author.add_roles(role)

    await message.channel.send('Done! You are now setup. In #other, type in !!help to learn how to invite people to your apartment.')
```

Here is the code that deals with invites:

```
if message.content.startswith('!!invite'):
    await message.channel.send('Inviting ' + message.content[8:] + "...")

    role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name=message.content[8:])
    await message.channel.set_permissions(role, send_messages=True, read_messages=True)

    inviteChannel = client.get_channel(694547722899816498)

    await inviteChannel.send('Hello {1}! {0.author.mention} has invited you to their apartment! Join them in {0.channel}!'.format(message, message.content[8:]))

    await message.channel.send('Invited ' + message.content[8:] + '.')
```

The code should accept a tag from the user (a role) and allow them to access the user's channel.

The bit that isn't working is when I try and set the permissions. Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/toffee/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "theBot.py", line 52, in on_message
    await message.channel.set_permissions(role, send_messages=True, read_messages=True)
  File "/home/toffee/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/abc.py", line 618, in set_permissions
    raise InvalidArgument('target parameter must be either Member or Role')
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: target parameter must be either Member or Role
```

How would I go about getting all the user's role from the tag given, and then filter any other roles but custom ones out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right I've figured it out. I needed to get the role from the ID first, so I used this code to get the role instead, which actually worked:

```
        await message.channel.send('Inviting ' + message.content[8:] + "...")

        print(message.content[12:-1])

        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=int(message.content[12:-1]))
        print(role)
        await message.channel.set_permissions(role, send_messages=True, read_messages=True)
```